# Performing PCA on properly scaled data

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, standardization

I would like to perform PCA on a dataset, however, not all of the data is in the same scale. Some variables are Height, Weight, Age, while others are Dribbles per Game, Shots per Game, Blocks per Game.

When I re-scale my data, can I use the standardizaiton method such that each newly transformed varaible has a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1? So my process would be take each value, subtract the mean, divide by the standard deviation.

Also, I have read in some cases for variable like height or weight, it is better to take the log-normal transformation? Once you do that though, the scale is not helpful.

When I perfrom the PCA in R, I planned on using the covariance matrix to see how much of the data I explain with my 2 principal components.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because I am not asking about correlation vs covariance.

Comment: You could consider using maximum likelihood Factor Analysis. The results are not tied to the scale used in the same way.

Comment: Yes you are. "So my process would be take each value, subtract the mean, divide by the standard deviation. " - this means using correlation. Please read the accepted answer in the linked thread.

Comment: Since I have scaled my variables, both the correlation and covariance then are the same?